# Xpages Rich Text validation

Tags: validation, xpages

Is there any way to validate a Rich Text I add a validateExpression but is doesn't work.

Thanks

```
<xp:inputRichText
        value="#{document1.Request}" id="inputRichText1" style="width:99.0%">
  <xp:this.validators>
    <xp:validateExpression 
          message="Attachment is missing">
    <xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript: if(getComponent("inputRichText1").getSubmittedValue()!== ''){
           return true
           }}]]></xp:this.expression>
</xp:validateExpression>
</xp:this.validators></xp:inputRichText>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `validatorRequired` is required in addition but doesn't help on its own.

If user clicks into RichText field and doesn't input anything then it's content gets set to

```
<p dir="ltr">
    &nbsp;</p>
```

and the test for empty value doesn't work anymore.

So, we have to eliminate this with replace() before we test for "".

```xml
<xp:messages
    id="messages1" />
<xp:inputRichText
    value="#{document1.Request}"
    id="inputRichText1"
    style="width:99.0%"
    disableClientSideValidation="true">
    <xp:this.validators>
        <xp:validateExpression message="Attachment is missing">
            <xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript: 
                var text = (value + " ").replace(/(<((?!img|a\s)[^>]+)>)|&nbsp;/ig, "").trim();                             
                return text !== "";
            }]]></xp:this.expression>
        </xp:validateExpression>
        <xp:validateRequired
            message="Attachment is missing" />
    </xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputRichText>
```

The regular expression eliminates all html tags `<...>` and `&nbsp;` except image tags `<img...>` and link tags `<a...>`.

Comment: Hermann, I wat to display error message as a list on the top of the page because I have seven mandatory field in this form that display error messages as a list on the top of the page

Comment: Insert `<xp:messages id="messages1"></xp:messages>` to your XPage then. It will show all error messages on one place.

Comment: Thanks Hermann if I click inside the rich text and don't insert any thing it display error message but if I don't click inside the rich text it display nothing.

Comment: I don't add validateRequired because it displays regular message.

Comment: I updated my code. I added the message "Attachment is missing" to `<xp:validateRequired ...>`, added `disableClientSideValidation="true"` and added `<xp:messages ... >`. This way,  you always get the message "Attachment is missing" if rich text field is empty and error messages are all together on top.

Comment: I extended the regular expression so that image and link tags don't get removed.

Comment: Thank you so much Knut Hermann, with disableClientSideValidation= "true" it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For standard components, I know validators are only triggered if there is a requiredValidator as well. Basically, if you're wanting to ensure content fits a particular criteria, the assumption is that you need to also validate that the field's not blank.

Comment: I want to check Rich Text is not blank not its content.

Comment: I'm not sure you're validation does that. Is submittedValue not blank if there's an attachment? My first step would be to check whether the validator is triggered and then, what submittedValue is. If the validator doesn't trigger, it could be because it expects a requiredValidator. If you just want to check an attachment has been added, you may need to move the validation to your save function.

Comment: When a user clicks submit button if rich text is blank it should display an error message because of this I used submittedValue().

Comment: Use the validatorRequired. No code to be written. Also INSIDE a validator there is a predefined variable value that points to that control's submitted value

Comment: @stwissel I have seven mandatory field in this form that display error messages as a list on the top of the page I want to display an error message for the rich text in this list. But with  validatorRequired it display regular error message.

Comment: You need to set "disableClientSideValidation" to true in the properties of that control or disable is for the entire app in the database properties